# How do I read the results of gradlew app:dependencies?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I'm running into an error when trying to run my project from Android Studio. I've found several answers to the issue itself, but one of them mentioned running `gradlew app:dependencies` from the AS terminal.

I ran it, and am not sure how to read some of the results. For example, I'm using AWS's DynamoDB, and according to their startup tutorial, I'm supposed to do this in my build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
}
```

The results of the `app:dependencies` call include this:

```
\--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+ -> 2.2.12
     +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.12 (*)
     +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.12 (*)
     \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.12
          \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.12 (*)
```

How do I read this? Does it mean that the ddp-mapper package lives in sdk-core, sdk-ddb, and sdk-s3, or something else entirely?

Comment: @CommonsWare what are the meaning of (*) and what it means arrow -> in this case.. I guess 2.+ will be changed to exact dependencies 2.2.12.. In my specific case I have com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 23.0.1

Comment: @Ewoks: Based on [this blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/08/gradle-goodness-getting-more-dependency.html), `(*)` means "we listed this dependency earlier, see it for any of its transitive dependencies". I have always interpreted the arrow as meaning "this is the specific version that we chose".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, nesting means "transitive dependencies". `aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper` is pulling in three other artifacts: `aws-android-sdk-core`, `aws-android-sdk-ddb`, and
`aws-android-sdk-s3`. That latter one *also* has a transitive dependency, pulling in `aws-android-sdk-core`.

Now, you'll notice that `aws-android-sdk-core` appears a lot. Gradle knows this and nets that down to a single copy of that dependency.

Comment: Thanks. AWS seems to add a ton of stuff that may not be necessary for what I'm doing, so I'm trying to find anything I can pull out.

Comment: @EmmyS: Yeah, I can't help you there, sorry. I use AWS server-side, but I have never tried their Android APIs.